# Spring JPA: no property id found for Object with `@Any` annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I wish to create an `Attachment` entity that may be related to entities of different types, so I am trying to use `@Any` annotation for that. My code is like this:

```
@Entity
public class Attachment{
    @XmlElement
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "containerType"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
            @MetaValue(targetEntity = TestApp.class, value = "TestApp")
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "container_id")
    private Object container;

    @XmlElement
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) //this I added cause Hibernate said so
    private String containerType;
}
```

My problem now is that when I start my app, DB initialization fails with:
`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Object! Traversed path: Attachment.container`

All the examples of using `@Any` I've found so far are exactly the same. So what is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've managed to overcome this by providing an `IAttachable` interface with `getId()` method and replacing `Object` with `IAttachable` in my relation definition.

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works so far.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the for field:
    @JoinColumn(name = "container_id")
    private Object container;

You use `JoinColumn`, but JPA can not find the ID field in `Object`. The meaning is, when you use `JoinColumn`, JPA needs to know the column name in current table, `Attachment` in this case, and the referenced column in the joined table, that is `container`.

But as you said, you want to let this table related to entities of different types. I think you can not do that. In my understanding, JPA is a little like 'static' explanatory. You can not make it 'dynamic'.

Comment: The problem here is that all examples I've found so far are just like the one I showed, so this is supposed to work, I guess.

Comment: Because, in the normal we use `JoinColumn `, the type of the field is an Entity, which has an `ID`. So by default, we don't need to add it, because JPA will use PK as referenced column